# Webdriver instance exits after Test Method for test class extending FluentTestNg

Tags: fluentlenium

Background: I am trying to write end-to-end selenium tests using Fluentlenium (in Java, fwiw)

I could use some help with trying to figure out whether there is a way to extend the life of a webdriver session beyond the scope of `@Test` method in TestNG, when extending `FluentTestNg`. Right now, I see the browser session just exit after one @Test method completes and a new one pops up at the start of the next `@Test` method. I would prefer to be able to use `@Test(dependsOnMethods = "previousMethod")` during UI Tests and hence, carry over the browser session to the next method.

I have Test class that extends `FluentTestNg`, with a `@BeforeClass` (even a `@BeforeSuite`) where I initialize the browser based on the value of system property then
call test methods. I have posted the snippet below.

```
public class LoginTest extends FluentTestNg {

@BeforeClass
    public static void setupClass() {

        List<String> browserList = Arrays.stream(DriverManagerType.values()).
                map(DriverManagerType::toString).collect(Collectors.toList());

        String browserName = CaseUtils.toCamelCase(System.getProperty("fluentlenium.webDriver"),true);

        if(browserList.contains(browserName)) {
            DriverManagerType driverManagerType = DriverManagerType.valueOf(browserName.toUpperCase());
            WebDriverManager.getInstance(driverManagerType).setup();
        }
    }

@Test
public void logIn() { 
// something
 }

@Test(dependsOnMethods = "logIn") 
public void logOut() { 
// some more thing to logout
}

}
```

The documentation does not discuss anything for such situations, hence, falling back on SO. I feel that someone out there might already have an answer or resolution, for this.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the problem

```
    @FluentConfiguration(driverLifecycle = ConfigurationProperties.DriverLifecycle.CLASS)
    public class LoginTest extends FluentTestNg {
    ..
    ..
    }
```